# I am new to python,can someone please point out what is wrong with this code,i am getting no errors

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, screen-scraping, mysql-python

So i am working on a project at the moment,and the code i have mentioned below is the last loop i want to perform where data from each list will be added to a mysql database row by row,

I am not getting while running the code, however as you can see, i have also put in a indicator to check whether the process has started or not and its not starting.

so i am unable to understand what the problem actually is.

1. Am i using the zip function properly?
2. I used the same loop in a different project of mine and it worked flawlessly

So can someone please help me out as in where i am going wrong with this:

```
for t,p,be,yb,pid,pty,ba,pa,pf,pag,cn in zip(Title  ,Price ,Beds ,Year_Built ,Property_ID ,Property_Type ,Baths ,Property_Area ,Property_Firm ,Property_Agent ,Contact_Number):
    csql.execute("insert into homefinder(title,price,beds,year,PID,ptype,baths,area,firm,agent,contact) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" , (t,p,be,yb,pid,pty,ba,pa,pf,pag,cn))


As per Jeff's instructions i ran a pdb on my code:
here are the results:
    c:\users\rishi\music\python\live project\homefinder\homefinder-selenium-test.py(163)<module>()
-> for t,p,be,yb,pid,pty,ba,pa,pf,pag,cn in zip(Title  ,Price ,Beds ,Year_Built ,Property_ID ,Property_Type ,Baths ,Property_Area ,Property_Firm ,Property_Agent ,Contact_Number):
(Pdb) next
> c:\users\rishi\music\python\live project\homefinder\homefinder-selenium-test.py(164)<module>()
-> csql.execute("insert into homefinder(title,price,beds,year,PID,ptype,baths,area,firm,agent,contact) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" , (t,p,be,yb,pid,pty,ba,pa,pf,pag,cn))
(Pdb)
> c:\users\rishi\music\python\live project\homefinder\homefinder-selenium-test.py(163)<module>()
-> for t,p,be,yb,pid,pty,ba,pa,pf,pag,cn in zip(Title  ,Price ,Beds ,Year_Built ,Property_ID ,Property_Type ,Baths ,Property_Area ,Property_Firm ,Property_Agent ,Contact_Number):
(Pdb)
--Return--
> c:\users\rishi\music\python\live project\homefinder\homefinder-selenium-test.py(163)<module>()->None
-> for t,p,be,yb,pid,pty,ba,pa,pf,pag,cn in zip(Title  ,Price ,Beds ,Year_Built ,Property_ID ,Property_Type ,Baths ,Property_Area ,Property_Firm ,Property_Agent ,Contact_Number):
(Pdb)
--Call--
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py(1279)_shutdown()
-> def _shutdown():
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py(1285)_shutdown()
-> tlock = _main_thread._tstate_lock
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py(1288)_shutdown()
-> assert tlock is not None
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py(1289)_shutdown()
-> assert tlock.locked()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py(1290)_shutdown()
-> tlock.release()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py(1291)_shutdown()
-> _main_thread._stop()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py(1292)_shutdown()
-> t = _pickSomeNonDaemonThread()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py(1293)_shutdown()
-> while t:
(Pdb)
--Return--
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\threading.py(1293)_shutdown()->None
-> while t:
(Pdb)
--Call--
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1928)shutdown()
-> def shutdown(handlerList=_handlerList):
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1935)shutdown()
-> for wr in reversed(handlerList[:]):
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1938)shutdown()
-> try:
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1939)shutdown()
-> h = wr()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1940)shutdown()
-> if h:
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1941)shutdown()
-> try:
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1942)shutdown()
-> h.acquire()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1943)shutdown()
-> h.flush()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1944)shutdown()
-> h.close()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1952)shutdown()
-> h.release()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1935)shutdown()
-> for wr in reversed(handlerList[:]):
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1938)shutdown()
-> try:
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1939)shutdown()
-> h = wr()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1940)shutdown()
-> if h:
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1941)shutdown()
-> try:
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1942)shutdown()
-> h.acquire()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1943)shutdown()
-> h.flush()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1944)shutdown()
-> h.close()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1952)shutdown()
-> h.release()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1935)shutdown()
-> for wr in reversed(handlerList[:]):
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1938)shutdown()
-> try:
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1939)shutdown()
-> h = wr()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1940)shutdown()
-> if h:
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1941)shutdown()
-> try:
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1942)shutdown()
-> h.acquire()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1943)shutdown()
-> h.flush()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1944)shutdown()
-> h.close()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1952)shutdown()
-> h.release()
(Pdb)
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1935)shutdown()
-> for wr in reversed(handlerList[:]):
(Pdb)
--Return--
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py(1935)shutdown()->None
-> for wr in reversed(handlerList[:]):
(Pdb)
--Call--
Exception ignored in: <async_generator object _ag at 0x0000001F852A1798>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\types.py", line 27, in _ag
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\bdb.py", line 50, in trace_dispatch
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\bdb.py", line 82, in dispatch_call
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 251, in user_call
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 351, in interaction
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 1453, in print_stack_entry
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\bdb.py", line 391, in format_stack_entry
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: 1) You haven't said what `Title`, `Bed_Bath`... are. 2) Do you know for fact that the loop is entered? 3) Are you sure all of the variables yield non-empty iterators? 4) https://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Hi Bobby,

To answer you questions:
title,,bedbath, etc were appended while running another for loop.
I know for a fact that the loop is not entered as "data append started" is not getting printed.
Yes i am sure, that none of the variables would be having non empty results, to avoid that i have put in a exception where in if the required data is not found then append as "NA"

Comment: I am not Bobby. The link is there to teach you about a dangerous practice you have in your code.

Comment: Oh sorry Amadan

Comment: Hi Amadan,

Can you please elaborate the dangerous practice, as the link you shared is for perl while i am using python

Comment: It is for anyone who uses SQL. There is a menu on the left side with many languages, Python included, but the core of it is contained in the XKCD comic in the page. The main idea is to never include input data in SQL statements without proper escaping, or a malicious agent could change or delete your database. `"...%s..." % (...)` does not constitute proper escaping, and is thus terribly insecure. Even if you think "this time I know where all the data is coming from", in the future it might change; and you might as well practice correct code, so you don't make a mess when it does matter.

Comment: I will have to look more into this,However Amadan can also tell me where am i going wrong with my code?

Comment: You've posted code that you've stated is not getting called... which means the problem is elsewhere. You should spend some time learning how to debug your code in the IDE that you are using. Put in some breakpoints and step through the code and look at variables state, code flow, etc. and see where the issue is. If you've found the issue and don't know how to solve it, then come back and edit this question and post an [mcve] with the error message, etc. that you received.

Comment: Hi Jeff,the reason why its not starting is because the first line of the loop is returning none, i am unable to understand why.

i have checked the values in all the lists, and there is no none value.